# How do I disable ligature in Firefox 8?

Tags: firefox

So I am viewing this page I just made on FF8 and I have the word "efficient," but the two f's don't show up at all. I bought the font Alwyn and I guess it does not have the [ligature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature).

I only see this on FF, so is there a way to turn ligatures off? (with js or css or somewhere in FF)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-moz-font-feature-settings: "liga=0"` should do the trick.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-font-feature-settings

Comment: The link has rotted, and when I search for `-moz-font-feature-settings` I only get the CSS specification. Where do I put this? Does it even still work with firefox 84?